# CSS Horizontal Navigation Bar Question

Tags: html, css, navigation

```
<style>
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}

#navlist{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 5px solid #ccc;
}

#navlist li{
    float: left;
}

#navlist li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 5px solid #ccc;
}

#navlist li a:hover{
    color:#c00;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#navlist a#current{
    color:#c00;
}



/*SEARCH*/

#navlist li input{
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-right: 5px solid #ccc; 
}

#navlist li input:hover{
    color: #c00;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#navlist li input #searchbar{
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
            <div>
                <ul id="navlist">
                    <li><a href="index.html" id="current" title="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="">Page 4</a></li>
                    <form action="search.asp">
                        <li><input id="searchbar" type="text" name="searchbar" size="15" value="INSERT SEARCH"/></li>
                        <li><input class="searchbut" type="submit" value="Search"/></li>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </div>

</body>
```

This is a horizontal navigation bar with a search bar. My question is two-fold. How can I make it that I specify a height such as `height:30px;` for the horizontal navigation and the top and bottom padding of each link and input field will fit exactly to match the specified container height (auto-size to specified height)?; I tried using `padding:100% 10px;` under `a{` and `input{` however that did not work. Secondly what selector do I type to modify the input classes separately (ex. `#navlist li input #searchbar{ size:15; }` )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of vertical padding, why not make the links `height: 30px;` and `line-height: 30px;`. Then, you don't have to worry about making the padding fit exactly because, if you make the line height equal to the height, the text will always be vertically centered.

Comment: You don't even need to say that they should be `height: 30px;` - simply adding the line height to the anchors will expand the nav's height.

Comment: That would work if I were just using links, however I have 5 links and 2 input fields. The 2 input fields are on a different size scale so the right hand borders are too small or too big and don't touch the bottom border when I try to make the link and the inputs the same height.

Comment: OK I misunderstood you, thank you very much, this exactly what I was trying for.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zk23Z/1/)

Hows that? Not exactly sure what you need. Let me know and I'll update when I get a chance.